# Can sparkSQL dataframe exceed the memory?

Tags: apache-spark

I`m using SparkSQL doing some calculation. Every 5 minutes there will be a new data frame comes in. I need to run calculation on the recent one week dataframe.

Which means I need to merge 12*24*7 = 2016 dataframes to a big one and run calculation.

The size is going to beyond my RAM size. All the nodes within my spark cluster have totally 128G memory which is not enough.

So I want to know what will happen if the dataframe too big to fit in memory? Will spark swap it out to disk temporarily? Do I need to explicitly ask spark to swap or it will done automatically?

Comment: There might be memory issues and also long lineage.

Comment: You really need to set up check points for this kind of job. It is highly likely that the job will fail. To answer your question, Spark automatically writes data to Disk (tmp) you do not need to set it, it is on by default (though you can switch it off). http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Comment: @GameOfThrows The code did fail due to out of memory. I issued a new question to describe my situation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36545306/why-my-spark-code-having-memory-leak Can you help to look and give some advice please?

Comment: @eliasah Thanks. My code did hit OutOfMemory issue. Can you give some advice on this kind of pattern?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't answer that ! It's too broad, it can be anything. Open a new question describing your issue. It seems to me that David has answered this one since you have accepted it

Comment: @eliasah Hi, Sorry I did not make it clear.. I already opened a new one here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36545306/why-my-spark-code-having-memory-leak). Yes I accepted david`s answer for this question. But I think your comment about lineage may be a clue to my new question here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have 2016 input files that you need to read in? If so, spark's read functions accept wildcards, so you can read them all at once as opposed to setting up some loop/read/merge functionality. And depending on your input files, the size of data frame in memory could be much smaller than the size of your saved files. So, it's possible your data frame will fit into memory.

To answer your question, Spark will automatically spill to disk as needed if it runs out of memory.